# BeautifulSoup - how to exclude a certain element from under a certain tag?

Tags: beautifulsoup, tags

I'm new to web scraping. I want to exclude img element which falls under 'p' tag. Here is my codes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = 'https://chhouk-krohom.com/%E1%9E%91%E1%9E%B8%E1%9E%83%E1%9E%93%E1%9E%B7%E1%9E%80%E1%9E%B6%E1%9E%99%E1%9F%A1%E1%9F%A4/'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(response.content, 'html.parser')

contents = soup.find_all(['h1', 'p'])
for content in contents:
    print(content)

content = soup.prettify()
with open('sutta.html', 'wt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(str(content))
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOctc.png)

So, I wanted to get all the texts from 'h1' and 'p' (there's only one 'h1', but many 'p'). The problem is with 'p'. For some reason, an image source falls under the 'p' (path: p.a.img). Since I wanted to output the file as html, the image (which is for the go-top button) is in the way. Therefore, I wanted to ask if there is a way to exclude that img in this case. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to get your goal simplest one is to use `.get_text()`, cause it will only return human readable text not HTML:

```
for content in contents:
    print(content.get_text())
```

Another approach is to `.decompose()` the `<img>` - So select all the concerning `<img>` iterate over `ResultSet` and decompose each. After that you can operate on these cleaned `soup`:

```
for e in soup.select('.go-top img'):
    e.decompose()

contents = soup.find_all(['h1', 'p'])
for content in contents:
    print(content)
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much! I've read the BS documentation about .decompose(), but didn't know how to implement it in my code. Turned out you just put it there before .find_all. How does it work here? It just gets saved there before the next operation? No function, no print...

Comment: Yes, simply `decompose()` the tags from your `soup` at first, after that `soup` do not contain any of them and you could operate on that cleaned `soup`. No additional handling needed.